# Bash- How to express 1 as 1.000

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
for i in {1..100}
do
result=$( echo "scale=3; sqrt($i)" | bc)
echo $result
done
```

Hi, when I run my code, it shows me the square root of the integers. However, it expresses 1 as 1 instead of 1.000. I want it to be 1.000 as well. I'm wondering how I can fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
for i in {1..100}
do
  result=$( echo "scale=3; (sqrt($i)/1)" | bc)
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! Could you explain how come it works as well?

Comment: Division with bc will result in floating point.